# Sharepoint Webpart load asynchronous on page load

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm just having a **webpart on a page** which consumes webservice of a RSS feed, converting into datatable displaying with my own design, because of which the **whole page load is slowed down.**

**What i wanted to do is to let the other webparts render and this webpart can take it's own time to load?**

Does anyone come across this kind of situation where the **webpart on page load is asynchronously loaded?**

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A WebPart cannot be loaded asynchronously as it is delivered within the page rendering process (in the end a web browser only understands HTML).

What you can do is to load the **content** of the WebPart asynchronously by using Javascript. So you could get your RSS feed via Javascript and a Webservice and load that after everything else has finished loading on the page.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163587.aspx